# How can I show my ads an equal number of times?

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I'm building my own advertisement platform, and I have a little problem. How can I show my ads an equal number of times?

So for example:

```
Name    |    Views

Ads 1   |    100

Ads 2   |    98

Ads 3   |    99
```

So my system need to show the ads with the least views, in this case "Ads 2 or Ads 3".
So all my ads follow each others views. So when my 3 ads have 3.000 views total, there should be 1.000 views on every view.

I'm coding in PHP, and I don't have an example, because I need inspiration how to fix my problem.

Comment: Hmm. Why not just query every time which ad has the lowest number of views, and then display that?

Comment: hmm.. I could also do that, but at the same time, the ads with the highest score, need to be showed 30% more than the other ads.

Comment: Now you're starting to reveal the *real* spec here. How are you defining "ads with the highest score"? Should the top 10% be shown 30% more? If you give us exact requirements, we can work this out for you. Right now, things are very fuzzy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select your least viewed add like this:

```
SELECT * FROM ads ORDERBY views ASC LIMIT 0, 1
```

This way, all the ads with less views will slowly catch up.

-- Edit, using your next requirement

```
probabilityForHighestScore = 30;
random = rand(0, 100);

if (random > probabilityForHighestScore)
    SELECT * FROM ads ORDERBY views ASC LIMIT 0, 1
else
    SELECT * FROM ads ORDERBY score DESC LIMIT 0, 1
```

If you need something else, you'd better explain you whole requirement first. Because if it is not clear for you, it won't be clear in your question, and the answers won't do what you want.

Comment: Yearh, also that way i was thinking to do it.
But i also need to do, so the ads are sort my highest score.

So the ads with the highest score have a bit more views that the second best ads and so on? :)

Comment: Edited with some additional code. But this is my last edit until you edit your question with the precise requirement you have.

Comment: I got it, you help me to get into the right way. Thanks alot! ;-)

Comment: @Simon: Just to make this clear, this code gives a 30% chance that the ad with the *most views* will be displayed, rather than the one with the highest score. If you have more than around 10 ads to display, this will give a single ad a *lot* more views in the long run, because once it gets in the lead, it will *always* be the record to get the 30% bump.

Comment: @AgentConundrum: indeed, the table in the question does not mention scores :) I have corrected the answer.

Comment: @AgentConundrum How would you do it? :)

Comment: @Simon: @MarvinLabs update goes a long way to mitigating the problem I saw. The updated code gives ~30% of views to whichever ad has the highest score, so it eliminates the problem of a the "highest view" record gaining inertia. The problem I see with this is that you're still giving a major boost to a *single* record - if one ad is rated at 9.9/10 and another is rated 9.8/10, that 9.9/10 record is going to get 30% of views, and the 9.8/10 record will share the remaining 70% of views with everyone else. I'd set it up to give the bump to the top n or top n% scoring records.

Comment: @Simon: Take a look at the edit I made to my answer outlining your options.

Comment: @Simon, a few notes: the above query could bring a system to stall (assuming a decent number of views) if you don't have an index on column views. As for the score, you don't really explain what that is; if it is modifier that makes certain ads show more often (not related directly to views) then you can make score modify how views are recorded so that sorting by views would still work. For example if you want to display certain add 10 times more often then other then you could count only ever 10th view. Also the above approach assumes views are updated with no delays.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have a database table containing information about these ads. You could add, if you don't already have it, a `views` field to that table. Then, whenever you need to display an ad, you just grab the one with the lowest view count, add 1 to it's view counter, and display the ad.

Edit:

The problem with @MarvinLabs solution, as I explain in the comments, is that it's giving a huge bonus to a single record.

Let's say you have 50 separate ads in your system. Let's also say that your highest scoring record has a score of 9.9/10, and your second highest scoring record has a score of 9.8/10. Both of these are very high scoring items, but if you use @MarvinLabs code, the highest scoring record will get 30% of all views, while the second highest scoring record will get 1.4% of all views (70 percent of all views divided across the 49 non-highest scoring ads).

What you might want to consider is allowing for a larger range of high scoring ads to be included. You can do this in any one of three ways:

First, you can set a threshold, or multiple thresholds, which divide a certain percentage of views to certain ranges of scores. For example, you could have it so that ads which score more than 9/10 get 30% of all views. You would do that like this:

```
$random = rand(1,100);
if ($random > 30) {
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM ads WHERE score >= 9 ORDER BY views ASC";
} else {
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM ads WHERE score < 9 ORDER BY views ASC";
}
```

The problem with this is that if you don't have any ads with a score above 9, you won't get anything back. For that reason, you probably don't want to use this method.

Second, you could spread your 30% of views across the top 5 or 10 ads:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ads 
WHERE id IN 
   (SELECT id 
    FROM ads 
    ORDER BY score DESC 
    LIMIT 10) 
ORDER BY views ASC;
```

This solves the problem of "what if I don't have any records above the threshold" while still spreading the "high score bonus" across more than just a single record. The problem with this, if you consider it a problem that is, is that it doesn't scale with the volume of ads you have on record. Whether you have 10 records or 10,000 records, you'll still give the bonus to just 10 (or 20, or 50.. whatever you set) records.

If you want to scale, you'll want the third solution.

The third solution is to set your limit based on a percentage of the total number of records in the table. Since MySQL doesn't have a built-in way of handling this, you'll need to workaround this in one of two ways:

One way to do it the lazy way and run two queries - one to get the current record count, and another to create a query based on it. For example:

```
$query1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ads";
//store result in $count
$percentage = round($count * 0.10); //get 10% of records
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM ads WHERE id IN " .
              "(SELECT id " .
              " FROM ads " .
              " ORDER BY score DESC " .
              " LIMIT " . $percentage . ") " .
          "ORDER BY views ASC"
```

A better way would be to avoid the second round-trip to the database and use a prepared statement:

```
SELECT @percentage := ROUND(COUNT(*) * 10/100) FROM ads;
PREPARE PERCENTAGE FROM
   SELECT * 
   FROM ads 
   WHERE id IN
      (SELECT id FROM ads
       ORDER BY score DESC
       LIMIT ?)
   ORDER BY views ASC;
EXECUTE PERCENTAGE USING @percentage;
```

Comment: Yearh, also that way i was thinking to do it.
But i also need to do, so the ads are sort my highest score.

So the ads with the highest score have a bit more views that the second best ads and so on? :)

Comment: Which do you want? Do you want to show the highest scoring ads, or do you want to keep the view count consistent across all ads? These are mutually exclusive goals.